# Facebook app shows only one of the items in the feed for instant articles

Tags: facebook-instant-articles

I configured the development feed from the web. Then I installed the app. Now the "Development" tab only shows one of the items. All of them have different link, date and guid.

Any idea/suggestion/...?

Thanks in advance.